# Javascript for loop to detect and insert child nodes/divs not working, detects and inserts first one only

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have created a function to add gradient swatches in a Bootstrap grid of col-md-3 's, and it is inserting the first one, but not subsequent ones. The new col-md-3 div is set globally as newSwatch with the other elements attached, and the function is below. Here first is the node we are attaching to the row

```
let newSwatch = document.createElement('div'); (has two other divs with class/id already set)
```

And the function is here, it is inserting the first swatch, but cant get the  for loop right to attach subsequent ones after that, below.>

```
 // Conditional statement to check if swatch exists before insertion
    swatch = document.querySelector('.row');
    element = document.getElementById("bg-gradient");
    //If it isn't "undefined" and it isn't "null", then it exists.
    if(typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null) {
        //alert('Element exists!');
        let i;
        swatch = document.querySelector('.row').childNodes[i];
        for (i = 0; i < swatch.length[0]; i++) {
        swatch[i].appendChild(newSwatch);
        gradDiv.style.backgroundImage = gradient;
        textDiv.innerHTML = `<h5>${hexValues}</h5><p>${hexValues}</p>`;
        }
    } else{
         //alert('Element Doesnt Exist!');
        // Set the swatch title
        //addTitle()
        swatch.appendChild(newSwatch);
        gradDiv.style.backgroundImage = gradient;
        textDiv.innerHTML = `<h5>${hexValues}</h5><p>${hexValues}</p>`;

    }
```

I think length is the wrong attribute, as the error is "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Any tips welcome

Thanks

Comment: A single `<div>` can only be in one place in the DOM. You have to create a new one every time you make an insertion.

Comment: swatch[0].length

Comment: Pointy: Yes it is inserting a new div, a  col-md-3 every time.

Comment: Supercool, I tried that and get this Cannot read property '0' of undefined